# Dealing with first order derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following equation:

$$Y=[(A_L L)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}+(A_H H)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}]^{{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}}$$

I have to compute $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}$.

What I got is: $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L} = A_L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} [(A_L L)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}+(A_H H)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}]^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}} L^{\frac{-1}{\sigma}} $

However, the author proposes the following rearrangement:

$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=A_L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} [(A_L)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}+(A_H)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} (H/L)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}]^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}}  $

How to get the latter expression?

Comment: Just take $L^{\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}$ out of the brackets and you have the form.

Comment: Am I allowed to move $L^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}$ out of the brakets? In this case I'm going to have $L^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}$ out of the brakets. Right?

Comment: Yes of course you are.

Comment: Thanks, so I put $L^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}$ out of the brakets, which becomes $L^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}$ , and I'm done. If you want to post the answer, do it so that I can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will simplify the question: Let us substitute $$A_L^{\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}=k, \frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}=u, (A_HH)^\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}=m^u.$$ Then we get, $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=k\bigg(kL^u+m^u\bigg)^{\tfrac{1}{\sigma-1}}L^{\tfrac{-1}{\sigma}}$$
As I mentioned in the comment, we take $L^\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}$, i.e. $L^u$ common, so we get $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=k\bigg(kL^u+m^u\bigg)^{\tfrac{1}{\sigma-1}}L^{\tfrac{-1}{\sigma}}=k\bigg(k+\bigg(\frac mL\bigg)^u\bigg)^{\tfrac{1}{\sigma-1}}L^{\tfrac{u}{\sigma-1}}\cdot L^{\tfrac{-1}{\sigma}}$$ Now we note that $\dfrac{u}{\sigma-1}-\dfrac{1}{\sigma}=0$ so we have $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=k\bigg(k+\bigg(\frac mL\bigg)^u\bigg)^{\tfrac{1}{\sigma-1}}=A_L^{\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}\left(A_L^{\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}+(A_HH/L)^{\tfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{\sigma-1}}.$$